# ASUS UX31A keyboard backlight turns off after the lid is closed and reopened

Tags: keyboard, asus-laptop

Close the lid and then open later and the keyboard backlight turns off. The fn+f4 key does not turn it back on. I have to restart the laptop to get the keyboard backlight back on. Is there a workaround?

ASUS UX31A

Windows 8 x64

---

Update: Here's the response I got from ASUS:

For your issue,there is not a way to control the backlight,it will be turn on/off automatically as the sorrounding.If you can not use the FN+F3/FN+F4 to adjust the backlight of the keyboard,the only way is restarting the laptop.

Comment: Do you have the latest BIOS? Also, do you have it set to for auto backlight? I think it is FN+a key to enable and disable the auto backlight level. It might be something with W8 that might be causing your issues - did you have it with W7?

Comment: I updated to the latest BIOS last night. Fixed some other issues but not the backlight. The auto sensor (FN+a) seems to have no effect. Didn't have Win 7 on long enough to notice if there was an issue there.

Comment: I wonder if that has anything to do with ATK. Perhaps the backlight got turned off somehow and W8 isn't letting it turn back on. Do your other FN + keys work?

Comment: What's ATK? Most of the other FN+keys work. The touchpad one also does not work (turn the touch pad on/off) but it didn't work in the store when I tried it. I'll head over to Best Buy an see if their display model works.

Comment: What touchpad driver are you using? Windows, Elantech or ASUS Smart Gesture? If you haven't installed anything you should download one from the support page. I'm happy with the Smart Gesture but some swear by the Elantech. Check your installed apps to see if ATK Package is installed. I'm pretty sure you need that for the FN keys to work. But, I have no experience with W8.

Comment: Bingo! ATK was it. Didn't realize the ATK Package had to be installed. I just assume all the junk they put on a PC is, well, junk. I'm also using smart gesture and am pretty happy with it. Thanks1

Comment: Glad we figured it out! I'm also using the Smart Gesture - it works better for me than the Elantech driver.

Answer (score 2):

The ASUS support team helped me fix this. The two drivers that they told me to install were [Chipset Version  V9.3.0.1021](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=369&m=UX31A&os=36&ft=23&f_name=Chipset_Intel_Win8_64_Z9301021.zip#Chipset_Intel_Win8_64_Z9301021.zip), and [ATKACPI Driver Version V1.0.0025](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=369&m=UX31A&os=36&ft=14&f_name=ATKPackage_Win7_Win8_Z100025.zip#ATKPackage_Win7_Win8_Z100025.zip).

After installing those two drivers everything works great!

*This is for Windows 8.1 (on the ASUS UX31A).*

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: Solved the issue of not having control of backlight on Win10 on GL752VL -- except using appropriate chipset and atk drivers

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and tried some things (BIOS, drivers etc.).

Finally I got it to install and switched it to **Instant On** (Windows 8 drivers from ASUS).

Voilà - keyboard backlight turns on after opening.